# What happened to Vamana?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, vamana

I know about Vamana Avatara of Lord Vishnu. But, Is any scriptures mention about what happens to Vamana after he defeated Bali?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of Vishnu's most famous incarnations is that of Vamana the dwarf. The story goes roughly as follows: the Asura (demon) Mahabali, grandson of Vishnu's devotee Prahlada, took over the three worlds by conducting a hundred Ashwamedha Yagnas (horse rituals). Indra went to Vishnu for help, so Vishnu incarnated as Vamana, the youngest son of Indra's parents Kashyapa and Aditi, and then he went to Mahabali's hundredth Ashwamedha Yagna. He asked Mahabali for three steps of land, and then he grew gigantic and used those steps to take back the three worlds for Indra and the gods.

But according to Rupa Goswami, an Acharya of the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect (which the popular organization ISKCON is a part of), this isn't the first time that Vishnu has incarnated as a dwarf; here is what he says in his Laghu-Bhagavatamrita:

> Lord Vamana appeared three times in this kalpa. During the reign of the first (Svayambhuva) Manu, He visited the sacrifice performed by Vaskala, the king of the danavas. Then, in the reign of Vaivasvata Manu, and visited the sacrifice performed by Dhundhu. Then, in the seventh catur-yuga of that manvantara, He appeared as the son of Kasyapa and Aditi. In this way, to accept a donation, He appeared three times as Lord Trivikrama.

The third incarnation is the famous one

Now, your question is regarding 3rd Vamana Avatar.

In the Srimad Bhagavatam, there's a description of the spouses and descendants of the Adityas, a group of 12 gods who are the sons of Aditi and the sage Kashyapa. The Adityas include Surya, Indra, Varuna, etc., but the youngest of the Adityas is Vamana, the dwarf incarnation of Vishnu, and this is what the Srimad Bhagavatam says about Vamana's family:

> By His own potency, the Lord, who has multifarious potencies, appeared in the form of a dwarf as Urukrama, the twelfth son of Aditi. In the womb of His wife, whose name was Kīrti, He begot one son, named Bṛhatśloka, who had many sons, headed by Saubhaga.

Vishnu Purana says this:

> For in like manner as the lord of the world, the god of gods, Janárddana, descends amongst mankind (in various shapes), so does his coadjutrix Śrí. Thus when Hari was born as a dwarf, the son of Adití, Lakshmí appeared from a lotus (as Padmá, or Kamalá)

I assume this Padma or Kamala is the same as Kirt.

So, According to these sources Vamana after defeating Mahabali married and had sons.

According to some other scriptures-

After Vamana defeated Bali in a cunning manner, he granted Bali a boon. The boon allowed Bali to visit and rule the netherworld (Patala), which is considered one of the lower realms of existence. Bali, with his devotion and righteousness, accepted the defeat gracefully and went on to become the ruler of Patala.

In some versions of the story, Vamana also revealed his true divine form to Bali after defeating him, acknowledging Bali's virtues and loyalty. Lord Vishnu, in his Vamana incarnation, then returned to his celestial abode, Vaikuntha.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Hindu mythology, the story of Vamana (the dwarf incarnation) and his encounter with King Bali is primarily found specifically in the story mentioned in the Bhagavata Purana (Canto 8, Chapters 15-23), the Vishnu Purana (Book 1, Chapter 21), and the Padma Purana (Uttara Khanda, Chapters 236-244).

According to these texts, after Vamana defeated Bali in a cunning manner, he granted Bali a boon. The boon allowed Bali to visit and rule the netherworld (Patala), which is considered one of the lower realms of existence. Bali, with his devotion and righteousness, accepted the defeat gracefully and went on to become the ruler of Patala.

In some versions of the story, Vamana also revealed his true divine form to Bali after defeating him, acknowledging Bali's virtues and loyalty. **Lord Vishnu, in his Vamana incarnation, then returned to his celestial abode, Vaikuntha.**

Hope this helps!